# Gridview getting called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a parent grid which calls two child grids. But for some unknown reason they are getting fired twice. I cant't really seem to figure out the problem with this code. Can anyone guide me?

Backend Code (C#):

```
protected void grdGrpPrntRpt_RowDataBound(object sender,
                                      GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox litGrp = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("litGrp");
            litGrp.Text =
              DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "GroupName").ToString();
            ViewState["GroupName"] = litGrp.Text;
            DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["ds"];
            DataView dv = ds.Tables[3].DefaultView;
            dv.RowFilter = "GroupName='" + litGrp.Text + "'";
            DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
            GridView gvinner = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("grdInnerMain");
            gvinner.DataSource = dt;
            gvinner.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //report error
    }
}


protected void grdInnerMain_RowDataBound(object sender,
                                      GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox litUsr = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("litUsr");
            litUsr.Text = 
                DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "FirstName").ToString();
            // string username=
            DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["ds"];
            DataView dv = ds.Tables[3].DefaultView;
            dv.RowFilter = "userName='" +
           DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserName").ToString().Replace("'",
               "''") + "' and GroupName='" + ViewState["GroupName"].ToString()
             + "'";
            DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
            totalPages = 0;
            totalCost = 0;
            GridView gvinner2 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("innerGrid");
            gvinner2.DataSource = dt;
            gvinner2.DataBind();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //report error
    }

}
protected void innerGrid_RowDataBound(object sender,
                              GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataView dv = 
                ((DataSet)ViewState["dspaper"]).Tables[0].DefaultView;
            dv.RowFilter = "paperid=" +
               Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,
                                         "paperid").ToString());
            DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = dt.Rows[0]["PaperName"].ToString();
            //  e.Row.Cells[2].Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, 
     "TotalPagesPrinted").ToString() == "0" ? DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, 
       "TotalPagesSent").ToString() : DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, 
       "TotalPagesPrinted").ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, 
       "TotalPage").ToString() == "0" ? DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, 
       "Pages_Sent").ToString() : DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,
               "TotalPage").ToString();
            // e.Row.Cells[3].Text = 
        Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString()).ToString("0.00");
            totalPages += Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString());
            totalCost += Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString());
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,
                   "Color").ToString() == "0" ? "B & W" : "Color";
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = totalPages.ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = totalCost.ToString("0.00");
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = 
                  CResourcesManager.GetString("grdHeaderMediaReport");
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text =
                  CResourcesManager.GetString("grdHeaderColorReport");
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text =
                  CResourcesManager.GetString("grdHeaderPagesReport"); ;
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = 
                CResourcesManager.GetString("grdHeaderTotalCostReport");
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```

Frontend Code:

```
<asp:GridView Width="100%" ID="grdGrpPrntRpt" runat="server" 
               AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="2" BorderWidth="0px" 
             ShowHeader="false" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                    OnRowDataBound="grdGrpPrntRpt_RowDataBound">

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table id="tblInnerHeader" runat="server"
                                 width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr bgcolor="gray" valign="top">
                                        <td width="20%" height="30px">
                                            &nbsp;
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="litGrp"
                           ForeColor="White" BackColor="Gray" CssClass="LabelText2"
                                                runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
                                                   BorderWidth="0"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="2%">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="78%" align="left">
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgMainShowHide" 
                                    runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/plus.jpg"
                                                OnClick="imgMainShowHide_Click" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table id="tblFirstInnerGrid" runat="server" 
                             visible="false" width="100%" cellspacing="2"
                                    cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:GridView Width="100%" 
               ID="grdInnerMain" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="2" 
              BorderWidth="0px" ShowHeader="false" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"

                        OnRowDataBound="grdInnerMain_RowDataBound">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <table id="tblHeader"
                  runat="server" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr bgcolor="Wheat" 
                                                               valign="top">
                                                                    <td width="20%" 
                                                              height="25px">
                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                        <asp:TextBox 
              ID="litUsr" ForeColor="Blue" BackColor="Wheat" CssClass="LabelText2"

              runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="2%">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="78%" 
                                                                      align="left">
                                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgShowHide" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/plus.jpg"
                                               OnClick="imgShowHide_Click" />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                            <table id="tblInnerGrid" 
                          runat="server" visible="false" width="100%" cellspacing="2"
                                                                cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                   <td align="center">
                                                                        <asp:GridView 
           ID="innerGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"

       CellSpacing="2" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeaderNoSorting" BorderWidth="0px"

          ShowFooter="true" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="98%" 
                    OnRowDataBound="innerGrid_RowDataBound">
                                                                            <Columns>
                                                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        <%-- <asp:Label ID="lblMedia" runat="server"></asp:Label>--%>
                                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Color" HeaderText="Color/ B & W" /> --%>
                                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Color/ B & W">
                                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        <%--   <asp:Label ID="lblColor" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Color").ToString()=="0" ? "B & W" :"Color" %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPagesPrinted" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />--%>
                                                                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                                                                    FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        <%--<asp:Label ID="lblPagesPrinted" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Color").ToString()=="0" ? "B & W" :"Color" %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Total_Cost" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                                                                    FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                            </Columns>
                                                                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeaderNoSorting" />
                                                                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternateRowStyle" />
                                                                            <RowStyle CssClass="GridRowStyle" />
                                                                            <FooterStyle CssClass="GridFooter" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                                        </asp:GridView>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>
                                                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternateRowStyle" />
                                                <RowStyle CssClass="GridRowStyle" />
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternateRowStyle" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="GridRowStyle" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

**Extra Information**

For some reason the event `grdGrpPrntRpt_RowDataBound` is called as many times as there is data in the next grid. It should terminate as soon as the entire data in the next two grids gets bound but it again calls it and repeats the entire process again.

Comment: you mean the "databound" event fired twice?

Comment: yes. my entire grid is getting called twice..

Comment: Could you provide some context as to where you are binding the data to  `grdGrpPrntRpt`? Everything seems OK from what I see.

Comment: gridview has got an EnableViewState property.make it true..then it will fire once only. The GridView control is re-created on postback based on the information that is stored in ViewState. If the GridView control includes a TemplateField or a CommandField with the CausesValidation property set to true, then the EnableViewState property must also be set to true to ensure that concurrent data operations, such as updates and deletes, apply to the appropriate row.

Comment: @hridyapv: tried. still the same.

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible due to `AutoEventWireUp` , It may be true in your code.
If it is, Please make it false. Thanks

Comment: Tried. it then doesn't load any of the data on my page.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you bind your GridView on some other event, maybe Page_Load or... If you bind your GridView on Page_Load, please do that on the following way:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

//bind your GridView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem should simply means that somehow you are calling grdGrpPrntRpt.DataBind() twice,

your implementation of nested gridview databinding seems to be correct so the problem

might be on the event that is data-binding your main grid.

Try commenting every single line of main grid DataBind and putting it once at the Page_Load

event, you might end up with another problem but you'll be closer to the solution.

Comment: my grid bind function is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

Always check where all you binding grid or call gridbinding function. Like:-

you might have call it on Page_Load to bind first time then you would have call it at imgMainShowHide_Click event to bind it to new values. hence binding grid two time, so make sure to bind only when !Ispostback on Page_Load and enable gridview viewstate to retain its state during postback.

Comment: my grid bind function is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the given back-end code and front-end code. You might look into [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1566460.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The RowDataBound for the grid fires number of times the number of rows present in the grid.

so make sure whether your parent grid has more than one record..

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you html code gridview

```
 OnRowCreated="gv_RowCreated"
```

is removed if you are using vb.net. Facing same issue.